# Center Plot title in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, center, ggtitle

This simple code (and all my scripts from this morning) has started giving me an off center title in ggplot2:

```
Ubuntu version: 16.04

R studio version: Version 0.99.896

R version: 3.3.2

GGPLOT2 version: 2.2.0
```

I have freshly installed the above this morning to try and fix this...

```
dat <- data.frame(
time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
total_bill = c(14.89, 17.23)
)

# Add title, narrower bars, fill color, and change axis labels
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, fill=time)) + 
  geom_bar(colour="black", fill="#DD8888", width=.8, stat="identity") + 
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  xlab("Time of day") + ylab("Total bill") +
  ggtitle("Average bill for 2 people")
```

[image]

Answer (score 517, accepted):

From the release news of `ggplot 2.2.0`: ["The main plot title is now left-aligned to better work better with a subtitle"](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/releases/tag/v2.2.0). See also the `plot.title` argument in `?theme`: "left-aligned by default".

As pointed out by @J_F, you may add `theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))` to center the title.

```
ggplot() +
  ggtitle("Default in 2.2.0 is left-aligned")
```

[image]

```
ggplot() +
  ggtitle("Use theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) to center") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Also take in consideration that if you have really long x/y axis text, probably a better approach would be to combine plot.title with plot.title.position: 
theme(
    plot.title.position = "plot",
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
    )

Answer (score 172):

As stated in the [answer by Henrik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41487043/4303162), titles are left-aligned by default starting with ggplot 2.2.0. Titles can be centered by adding this to the plot:

```
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

However, if you create many plots, it may be tedious to add this line everywhere. One could then also change the default behaviour of ggplot with

```
theme_update(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Once you have run this line, all plots created afterwards will use the theme setting `plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)` as their default:

```
theme_update(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
ggplot() + ggtitle("Default is now set to centered")
```

[image]

To get back to the original ggplot2 default settings you can either restart the R session or choose the default theme with

```
theme_set(theme_gray())
```

Answer (score 16):

The `ggeasy` package has a function called `easy_center_title()` to do just that. I find it much more appealing than `theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))` and it's so much easier to remember.

```r
ggplot(data = dat, aes(time, total_bill, fill = time)) + 
  geom_bar(colour = "black", fill = "#DD8888", width = .8, stat = "identity") + 
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  xlab("Time of day") +
  ylab("Total bill") +
  ggtitle("Average bill for 2 people") +
  ggeasy::easy_center_title()
```

[image]

Note that as of writing this answer you will need to install the development version of `ggeasy` from GitHub to use `easy_center_title()`. You can do so by running `remotes::install_github("jonocarroll/ggeasy")`.

Answer (score 8):

If you are working a lot with graphs and ggplot, you might be tired to add the theme() each time. If you don't want to change the default theme as suggested earlier, you may find easier to create your own personal theme.

```
personal_theme = theme(plot.title = 
element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Say you have multiple graphs, p1, p2 and p3, just add personal_theme  to them.

```
p1 + personal_theme
p2 + personal_theme
p3 + personal_theme

dat <- data.frame(
  time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner"), 
levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
  total_bill = c(14.89, 17.23)
)
p1 = ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, 
fill=time)) + 
  geom_bar(colour="black", fill="#DD8888", 
width=.8, stat="identity") + 
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  xlab("Time of day") + ylab("Total bill") +
  ggtitle("Average bill for 2 people")

p1 + personal_theme
```

Answer (score 0):

ggeasy package did it well for me its so easy once you run it with the Packman::p_load package

Helper functions for making using ggplot2 easier.[Package ggeasy version 0.1.4 Index]

Comment: Pleas provide the code used for this question.