# How to center ggplot plot title

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

The "lege artis" way to center justify a plot title in ggplot - [plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675778/center-plot-title-in-ggplot2) - centers the title over plot area *excluding axis labels*.

This can get ugly when the axis labels are very long, such as this plot of songs in Mary Poppins Soundtrack vs. their character length.

[image: length of songs in Mary Poppins Soundrack]

```
library(tidyverse)

mary_poppins <- data_frame(song = c("Overture", "Sister Suffragette", "The Life I Lead", "The Perfect Nanny", "A Spoonful of Sugar", "Pavement Artist", "Jolly Holiday", "Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious", "Stay Awake", "I Love to Laugh", "A British Bank", "Feed the Birds ", "Fidelity Fiduciary Bank", "Chim Chim Cher-ee", "Step in Time", "A Man Has Dreams", "Let's Go Fly a Kite"
))

mary_poppins <- mary_poppins %>%
  mutate(len = nchar(song))

ggplot(data = mary_poppins, aes(x = reorder(song, len), y = len)) +
  geom_col(fill = "firebrick") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_light() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(size = rel(1.5)),
        plot.title = element_text(size = rel(2.5), face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, 
                                  margin = margin(t = 10, b = 20, unit = "pt"))) +
  ggtitle("Mary Poppins") +
  ylab("Lenght of title (characters)")
```

Is there a way to center the title over the *total plot area*, i.e . including the area taken over by axis labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternately, you can use `gridExtra::grid.arrange` and `grid::textGrob` to create the title without needing to pad it visually. This basically creates a separate plot object with your title and glues it on top, independing of the contents of your `ggplot` call.

First store your whole `ggplot` call in a variable, e.g. `p1`:

```
grid.arrange(textGrob("Mary Poppins", 
               gp = gpar(fontsize = 2.5*11, fontface = "bold")), 
             p1, 
             heights = c(0.1, 1))
```

You have to translate your `theme()` settings to `gpar()`. The base size of `theme_light` is 11, which is where the 2.5*11 comes from (and the 2.5 from your `rel(2.5)`).

[image]

The advantage here is that you know your title will be truly centered, not just close enough by eye.

Comment: thank you - this is indeed a neater solution than padding spaces!

Answer (score 8):

A simple way to solve the problem is to add the following to the plot:

```
theme(plot.title.position = 'plot', 
      plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

The first part tells `ggplot` to use the entire plot as a reference for the centering, and the second part centers the title.

Answer (score 6):

Short solution I've found:

```
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = -0.2))
```

*hjust* parameter controls distance from the left alignment to the y axis. Negative values move text to the left

Answer (score 3):

Solution adding white space to centre title:

Add spaces after the title with:

```
ggtitle(paste0("Mary Poppins", paste0(rep("", 30), collapse = " ")))
```

For the output like this:

[image]

Not perfect solution, but works.

Answer (score 2):

As I replied in an essentially [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52469245/consistently-center-ggplot-title-across-panel-not-plot/60436896#60436896), you can use the `patchwork` library and it's `plot_annotation`, so you'll have:

```
library(tidyverse)

mary_poppins <- data_frame(song = c("Overture", "Sister Suffragette", "The Life I Lead", "The Perfect Nanny", "A Spoonful of Sugar", "Pavement Artist", "Jolly Holiday", "Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious", "Stay Awake", "I Love to Laugh", "A British Bank", "Feed the Birds ", "Fidelity Fiduciary Bank", "Chim Chim Cher-ee", "Step in Time", "A Man Has Dreams", "Let's Go Fly a Kite"
))
mary_poppins <- mary_poppins %>%
  mutate(len = nchar(song))

ggplot(data = mary_poppins, aes(x = reorder(song, len), y = len)) +
  geom_col(fill = "firebrick") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_light() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(size = rel(1.5))) +
  patchwork::plot_annotation("Mary Poppins", 
        theme = theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(2.5), face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, 
                                  margin = margin(t = 10, b = 20, unit = "pt")))) +
  ylab("Lenght of title (characters)")
```

Since `plot_annotation` is designed for multipanel plots, it will not inherit the theme of the plot you are constructing, so you need to give it separately. It will however honor any global theme.

The resulting plot is (hopefully) what you need.

[image: plot with centered title]

Comment: no a typical {patchwork} use case, but it does work - thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a hurry, adding spaces after title in ggtitle will also work...

```
ggtitle("Mary Poppins                                 ") +
```

Output:
[image: Center Mary Poppins Title]