# Consistently center ggplot title across PANEL not PLOT

Tags: r, ggplot2

The default alignment is for a ggplot title to be left-aligned to the plot.background element. Others have noted that you can use `plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)` to center the title.

- [How to center ggplot plot title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287086/how-to-center-ggplot-plot-title)
- [Center Plot title in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675778/center-plot-title-in-ggplot2?noredirect=1&lq=1)

However, I want to center the title across the entire panel as oppose to just the plot. I have done this in the past by modifying the `hjust` to push the title so that it appears centered, but value of `hjust` is dependent on the length of the title which makes it really tedious to set when I'm batch-producing graphs.

Is it possible to consistently set the title elements of a ggplot to be centered across the panel.background?

```r
library(reprex)
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)

mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "model") %>% 
  top_n(8,wt) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x =model, y = wt))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(title="This title is left-aligned to the plot")
```

[image]

```r
mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "model") %>% 
  top_n(8,wt) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x =model, y = wt))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(title="This title is center-aligned to the plot width.")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

```r
mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "model") %>% 
  top_n(8,wt) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x =model, y = wt))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(title="Short title, still works")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

```r
mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "model") %>% 
  top_n(8,wt) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x =model, y = wt))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(title="This title is roughly center-aligned to panel")+ 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.37)) # I know I can adjust this, but it would require a manual fix each time
```

[image]

## Suggestion by @user20650

```r
p <- mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "model") %>% 
  top_n(8,wt) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x =model, y = wt))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()+
  #labs(title="Short title, still works")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) 

gridExtra::grid.arrange( top=grid::textGrob("This title is center-aligned to panel"),p  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-09-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: one way would be to rbind a textGrob with the title to the plot. Here is a way using grid.arrange that does the work for you `gridExtra::grid.arrange(
  top=grid::textGrob("This title is roughly center-aligned to panel"),  p )`

Comment: @user20650, this looks good, I had looked into Grid.arrange before but not like this. Is there an argument that will allow me to get rid of the padding if I stack another textGrob for the subtitle? If i use your `gridExtra::grid.arrange(top=grid::textGrob("This title is roughly center-aligned to panel"),
                        grid::textGrob("subtitle"), p )`, the textgrobs are definitely centered across the entire panel but there is a lot of vertical spacing. Any way to reduce this? Ideally I want to keep the title and subtitle text separate so I can style them differently.

Comment: `grid.arrange(
  top=grobTree(textGrob("This title"),
               textGrob("\n\nThis subtitle", gp=gpar(cex=0.8))),  p,  padding=unit(2, "line") )` : not sure how robust it will be as title fontsize etc is increased.

Comment: pls see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630020/changing-multiple-line-title-in-multiplot-ggplot2-using-grid-arrange

Comment: @user20650, Thanks! For now, I think I'll go with your suggestion. It actually works pretty well since the title and subtitle font sizes are standardized across all the graphs so once I figured out the right number of new lines to put in the subtitle text it did not need to change. I'll update my question with your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to center ggplot plot title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287086/how-to-center-ggplot-plot-title)

Comment: Is it possible to align the title with the left side of the bars?

Answer (score 6):

There is now the option in theme to call `plot.title.position` to center the plot title to the entire plotting area, not just the plot panel. If you set `plot.title.position = "plot"` in `theme()`, it will center the title and subtitle to the whole plotting area, not just above the panel.

```
library(reprex)
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)

mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "model") %>% 
  top_n(8,wt) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x =model, y = wt))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(title="This title is center-aligned to the plot width.")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        plot.title.position = "plot")
```

[image: This title is center-aligned to the plot width.]

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to change the position of the title grob so that it starts from the left edge:

```
p <- mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "model") %>% 
  top_n(8,wt) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x =model, y = wt))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(title="This title is left-aligned to the plot") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

library(gridExtra)
g <- ggplotGrob(p)
g$layout$l[g$layout$name == "title"] <- 1
grid::grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: I like this solution because it allows me to continue to use the labs arguments, but I'm worried about saving as a png? My workflow after creating the graph is to use `ggsave` to save as a png. It seems like using `ggplotGrob` is not one of the accepted objects that ggsave accepts?

Comment: `ggsave("test.png")` works for me, since it defaults to saving the last plot displayed.  Or perhaps `ggsave("test.png", arrangeGrob(g))`, per the discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059099/saving-grid-arrange-plot-to-file.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is  to use the `patchwork` library and it's `plot_annotation`, so you'll have:

```
mtcars %>% 
     rownames_to_column(var = "model") %>% 
     top_n(8,wt) %>% 
     ggplot(aes(x =model, y = wt))+
     geom_col()+
     coord_flip()+
     patchwork::plot_annotation(title="This title is very long and centered on the whole plot", 
          theme = theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)))
```

[image]